# Does SVN Compress the binary content?

Tags: svn, compression

I was wondering whether SVN actually compresses the binary content on the server during Commits? I know that the binary store the diffgrams for comparison and versioning but wondered whether a new file commited would occupy the same volume on the server as it does on the client pc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe so.

From here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL

> ```
>   * libz  (REQUIRED for client and server)
> ```

```
     Subversion uses zlib for compressing binary differences.
     These diff streams are used everywhere -- over the network,
     in the repository, and in the client's working copy.
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Subversion compresses new files, as well as changes. (The server doesn't care if the file is text or binary.)

Note, however: if the file you are adding is already compressed (e.g. a zip archive, an mp3 file, a JPEG, a GIF) subversion won't be able to make it any smaller.