# Does Subversion include compression?

Tags: svn, csv, compression

I have a subversion server. On this server I have a folder `C:/svn` that contain the repositories of 4 projects. Now, one of these projects in particular is very large, containing approximately 500 MB of CSV files. However, after I've committed all of them to the SVN server, the `C:/svn` folder is only 86MB.

How can this be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does SVN Compress the binary content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458182/does-svn-compress-the-binary-content)

Comment: And a very relevant question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332833/how-exactly-does-subversion-store-files-in-the-repository

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: If someone could tell me if it's physically possible that the size of the repository is less than a fifth the size of the files it contains, and if that's at all likely, I'll accept that answer.

Comment: you have already proved its possible, right?

Comment: Perhaps :P So is that a confirmation? For all I know subversion stores files outside the repository folders. That's why I'm asking :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SVN does perform compression on the deltas and the repo contents: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace

Comment: What about 'pristine' files in `.svn` folder of working copies?

Comment: @TomaszGandor: No compression, just open them and have a look.