# Download over SVN fast for small files, slow for big files

Tags: svn, networking, throughput

I am downloading files through a site-to-site VPN using SVN. When java/class files are downloaded the speed is 400kb/s, but when .jar files are dowloaded the speed drops down to 10kb/s. Any ideas?

Comment: Ben Reser left an interesting comment. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

A java file being much smaller than a jar (which is a big binary file, acting as a zip archive), the average speed will seem much faster, since the small file (a few KB) is downloaded in less time than svn polls the download speed.
That gives the *impression* of a high *average* speed.

But for a big file, svn has the time to poll multiple times that same download speed, and the *actual* speed is revealed (over a longer period of time).

---

Another aspect which can influence the speed transfer is the [double-compression issue](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/Double-compression-over-HTTPS-td174664.html) on https session:

> when OpenSSL is built with zlib, it will automatically compress all data sent over an SSL connection. You can see this in the initial handshake "Client Hello" and "Server Hello" where client and server agree on the compression mechanism to be used.
>
> **If the data being sent or received is already compressed, OpenSSL will compress it a second time**. This can happen when already compressed binaries like .gif or .zip are sent, or when the server uses gzip encoding for a http response. **This can have impact on performance and memory usage**.

---

[Ben Reser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2089194/ben-reser) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399241/download-over-svn-fast-for-small-files-slow-for-big-files/21399905?noredirect=1#comment32313438_21399905):
(Ben is a Full Committer/PMC Member of [Apache Subversion project](http://subversion.apache.org/) and [httpd project](http://httpd.apache.org/))

> You can actually end up with up to 3 layers of compression.
>
> - The plaintext file may be compressed (user controlled),
> - the subversion diff format sent over the network can be compressed (controlled via `-c` for `svnserve` and `SVNCompressionLevel` for `httpd`),
> - and the on disk repository delta format can be compressed (will be configurable in `fsfs.conf` in 1.9).
>     The last bit is known to be a significant drain on compressed file transfer speeds and until 1.9, you can't really do anything about it other than avoiding adding compressed files to SVN.

Comment: Hi, I feel this is only part of the truth. I downloaded using SFTP a big zip file and average speed was 200kb/s. The machine is the same as where the SVN resides on. I feel that only compressed files through SVN are slow (10kb/s).

Comment: @user1340582 I agree. Although sftp and svn download are quite different.

Comment: @user1340582 are you using an https url for your svn repo that you are downloading? If yes, I have edited my answer.

Comment: I am using svnserve withoutt https for SVN. I am not sure how it is compressed, if it is at all...

Comment: @user1340582 yet, a double compression could still be the issue here. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/458211/6309. But also http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.optimization.compression

Comment: You can actually end up with up to 3 layers of compression.  The plaintext file may be compressed (user controlled), the subversion diff format sent over the network can be compressed (controlled via `-c` for `svnserve` and `SVNCompressionLevel` for httpd), and the on disk repository delta format can be compressed (will be configurable in fsfs.conf in 1.9).  The last bit is known to be a significant drain on compressed file transfer speeds and until 1.9 you can't really do anything about it other than avoiding adding compressed files to SVN.

Comment: @BenReser Thank you for those points. I have included them in the answer for more visibility.